Lossy conversion between long double and double
I was cought by suprise that the following code returns false for gcc 13 and clang 18. Why does this happen? Isn't the number 8.1 representable in both formats?
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    const long double val = 8.1L;
    const double val2 = static_cast<double>(val);
    const long double val3 = static_cast<long double>(val2);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (val == val3) << '\n';

    return 0;
}


print out sizeof(double) and sizeof(long double).  If long double is larger it means it can be more precise, it has more bits.  This is important because .1 is not representable in base 2, you get a close approximation instead.

This depends not only on the compiler, but also the underlying environment (OS, hardware) and standard library used. There are some systems where sizeof(double) == sizeof(long double) is true, and there are systems where it's false.

Shortly after writing the question I realized it's not exactly representable and therefore could differ in both formats.

No 8.1 is not representable. Like 1/3 = 0.33333.... in decimal (no matter how many digits you throw at it, it is still not 1/3). Same for "8.1" in binary 1000.0001 1001 1001 [1001].... (the 1001 group start repeating infinitely)


Isn't the number 8.1 representable in both formats?

No, 8.1 is not representable in any floating-point format that uses two for its base.
If a number is representable in a floating-point format, it is representable in a form ±M•be where b is the base used for the format and M and e are integers. There are bounds on M and e that depend on the format, and the M portion is often written as a fixed-point number instead of an integer, but this is just a scale change. Representation with an integer is mathematically equivalent.
With base two, 8.125 can be represented as +65•2−3, because 8.125•23 = 65. However, there is no power of two we can multipy 8.1 by to get an integer.  8.1•2 = 16.2.  16.2•2 = 32.4.  32.4•2 = 64.8.  64.8•2 = 129.6.  129.6•2 = 259.2.  259.2•2 = 518.4.  You can see the digit after the decimal point is looping:  .2, .4, .8, .6, .2, .4, .8, .6, .2,… It will never go away.
8.1 in binary is 1000.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011…2.
The format commonly used for double, IEEE-754 binary64, has 53 bits for its significand. When 8.1 is converted to this format it will be rounded to 53 bits. (The result of this rounding is 8.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375.)
I do not know what format your implementation is using for long double, but it likely has considerably more than 53 bits, say p bits. When 8.1 is rounded to this format, it is rounded to p bits. Your long double variable val gets this rounded value.
When static_cast<double>(val) is evaluated, this value is rounded to 53 bits, and val2 gets that value. It is a different value from val.
